# Make an int search(Object o) method for a stack that uses nodes

Tags: java, search, linked-list, stack, nodes

I'm trying to make a generic stack and queue class that uses the generic node class. It has `empty()`, `pop()`, `peek()`, `push()`, and a `search()` method. I know there is a built-in `Stack` class and stack `search` method but we have to make it by using the `Node` class.

I am unsure of how to make the `search` method. The `search` method is supposed to return the distance from the top of the stack of the occurrence that is nearest the top of the stack. The topmost item is considered to be at distance 1; the next item is at distance 2; etc.

My classes are below:

```
import java.io.*; 
import java.util.*;

public class MyStack<E> implements StackInterface<E>
{
    private Node<E> head;
    private int nodeCount;

    public static void main(String args[]) {
    }
    
    public E peek() {
        return this.head.getData();
    }
   
    public E pop() {
        E item;
        item = head.getData();
        head = head.getNext();
        nodeCount--;
        return item;
    }
    
    public boolean empty() {
        if (head==null) {
            return true; 
        } else {
            return false;
        }
    }
   
    public void push(E data) {
        Node<E> head = new Node<E>(data);
        nodeCount++;
    }
   
    public int search(Object o) {
        // todo
    }
}

public class Node<E>
{
    E data;
    Node<E> next;
    // getters and setters  
    public Node(E data) 
    { 
        this.data = data; 
        this.next = null; 
    } 
    public E getData() {
        return data;
    }
    public void setData(E data) {
        this.data = data;
    }
    public Node<E> getNext() {
        return next;
    }
    public void setNext(Node<E> next) {
        this.next = next;
    }
}

public class MyQueue<E> implements QueueInterface<E>
{
    private Node<E> head;
    private int nodeCount;
    Node<E> rear;
    public MyQueue() 
    { 
        this.head = this.rear = null; 
    } 
    
    public void add(E item){
        Node<E> temp = new Node<E>(item);
        if (this.rear == null) { 
            this.head = this.rear = temp; 
            return; 
        }  
        this.rear.next = temp; 
        this.rear = temp; 
    }
    
    public E peek(){
        return this.head.getData();
    }
    
    public E remove(){ 
        E element = head.getData();
        Node<E> temp = this.head;
        this.head = this.head.getNext();
        nodeCount--;
        return element;
    }
}
```

After working on it based off of the first comment I have this:

```
public int search(Object o){
    int count=0;
    Node<E> current = new Node<E> (head.getData());
    while(current.getData() != o){
        current.getNext();
        count++;
    }
    
    return count;
}
```

It doesn't have any errors but I cannot tell if it is actually working correctly. Does this seem correct?

Comment: Start with a `current` at `head` and call `current=current.getNext()` until `current.getData()` equals the thing you are looking for. Count how man times you did that.

Comment: So would current be a new node?

Comment: Shouldn't it be ``public int search(E element)``?

Comment: @NomadMaker The signature for Java's [`Stack#search`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Stack.html#search-java.lang.Object-) is `public synchronized int search(Object o)`. Therefore, I think it is correct as written in the question.

Answer (score 0):

It needs the following improvements,

1. search method should have parameter of type 'E'. So, the signature should look like  `public int search(E element)`
2. start the count with 1 instead of 0.As you have mentioned **topmost item is considered to be at distance 1**
3. initialize current with head, because creating a new node with data value of head(new node(head.getData())) will create an independent node with data same as head node; and the while will run only for the head node as current.getNext() will be null always. `Node<E> current = head` will create another reference variable pointing to the head.
4. Instead of **!=** in condition, use                                               `if( !current.getData().equals(element.getData())) )`
5. If using your own class as data type, don't forget to override **equals** method.
6. Change `current.getNext();` to `current = current.getNext();`

Answer (score 0):

You have problems with other method. Pay attention on `top == null`. To calculate `search()` all you need is just iterate over the elements and find position of required value:

```
public class MyStack<E> {

    private Node<E> top;
    private int size;

    public void push(E val) {
        Node<E> node = new Node<>(val);
        node.next = top;
        top = node;
        size++;
    }

    public E element() {
        return top == null ? null : top.val;
    }

    public E pop() {
        if (top == null)
            return null;

        E val = top.val;
        top = top.next;
        size--;
        return val;
    }

    public boolean empty() {
        return size == 0;
    }

    public int search(E val) {
        int res = 1;
        Node<E> node = top;

        while (node != null && node.val != val) {
            node = node.next;
            res++;
        }

        return node == null ? -1 : res;
    }

    private static final class Node<E> {

        private final E val;
        private Node<E> next;

        public Node(E val) {
            this.val = val;
        }

    }
}
```

Comment: Your signature of `search` is not compatible with `java.util.Stack#search`. The `!=` operator compares objects by reference which is most likely not what is desired here. Imagine the stack holds a string... you would need to pass the same *instance* of this string to get a match. Therefore `equals()` is more appropriate when the argument to be searched is not `null` itself. The renames of `head` to `top` and `data` to `val` are not necessary and might confuse the OP, the same goes for nesting `Node` within `MyStack` and removing the getters and setters.

Comment: @Matt `java.util.Stack` is **not reccomended to use**. Correct implementation of `stack data structure` in `Java` is `Dequeue<> stack = new LinkedList<>()`!

Comment: I did not recommend to use `Stack` but **just referenced it** for this reason: OP wants to build an own stack implementation with a `search` method whose contract matches that one of `Stack`. A `Deque` does not offer a `search` method. I agree, that the `Deque` interface and its implementations should be used in preference to `Stack`. However, I strongly disagree that `LinkedList` is the *correct* implementation thereof, especially when you need concurreny. There are several implementations for different use cases and they should be used appropriately.

Comment: @Matt i am not talking about concurency.

Answer (score 0):

I assume your `MyStack` class should be compatible with the `Stack` class provided by Java as you mention it in your question. This means that your signature `public int search(Object o)` matches the signature of [`java.util.Stack#search`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Stack.html#search-java.lang.Object-) (apart from `synchronised`).

To implement the `search` method using your `Node` class, we need to traverse the stack and return the index of the first (uppermost) match. First, assign `head` to a local variable (`current`). Then you can create a loop where you `current.getNext()` at the end to get the next element. Stop if the next element is `null` as we have reached the end of the stack. In the loop, you either count up the `index` or return this index when the current element's data matches the argument `o`.

The evaluation needs to be able to deal with `null` values for your argument `o`. Therefore, you need to check for `null` first and adjust your logic accordingly. When `o` is `null`, do a `null`-check against `current.getData()`. If `o` is not `null`, check if `current.getData()` is equal to `o` with `equals()`.

**Here is a working example:** *(compatible with `java.util.Stack#search`)*

```
public int search(Object o) {
    int index = 1;
    Node<E> current = head;
    while (current != null) {
        if (o == null) {
            if (current.getData() == null) {
                return index;
            }
        } else {
            if (o.equals(current.getData())) {
                return index;
            }
        }
        current = current.getNext();
        index++;
    }
    return -1; // nothing found
}
```

---

*To test this, you can write a simple unit test with JUnit like this:*

```
@Test
public void testMyStackSearch() {
    // initialize
    final MyStack<String> stack = new MyStack<>();
    stack.push("e5");
    stack.push("e4");
    stack.push(null);
    stack.push("e2");
    stack.push("e1");

    // test (explicitly creating a new String instance)
    assertEquals(5, stack.search(new String("e5")));
    assertEquals(3, stack.search(null));
    assertEquals(2, stack.search(new String("e2")));
    assertEquals(1, stack.search(new String("e1")));
    assertEquals(-1, stack.search("X"));
}
```

Since you have already a reference implementation, you can replace `MyStack` with `Stack` (`java.util.Stack`) and see if your asserts are correct. If this runs successfully, change it back to `MyStack` and see if your implementation is *correct*.

---

***Note:** I do not recommend to actually use the [`Stack`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Stack.html) implementation in Java. Here, it just serves as a reference implementation for the `java.util.Stack#search` method. The [`Deque`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Deque.html) interface and its implementations offer a more complete and consistent set of LIFO stack operations, which should be used in preference to [`Stack`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Stack.html).*