# NullPointerException error when unit testing

Tags: java, nullpointerexception, stack, nodes

When I unit test my `pop` and `peek` methods for my `MyStack` class, I encounter a `NullPointerException` relating to the `getData` method of my node class.

I cannot tell why and I am wondering if anyone has any ideas on how to fix it and make it so that there is not a `NullPointerException`. I have tried editing how the node works and how `getData` itself works but cannot find a solution and since cannot figure out the problem. Any help would be very much appreciated

```
import java.io.*; 
import java.util.*;

public class MyStack<E> implements StackInterface<E>
{
    public Node<E> head;
    public int nodeCount = 0;

    public static void main(String args[]) {
    }

    public E peek() {
        return head.getData();
    }

    public E pop() {
        if (nodeCount == 0) {
            throw new EmptyStackException();
        }
        E item = head.getData();
        head = head.getNext();
        nodeCount--;
        return item;
    }

    public boolean empty() {
        if (head == null && nodeCount == 0) {
            return true;
        } else {
            return false;
        }
    }
    
    public void push(E data) {
        Node<E> head = new Node<E>(data);
        nodeCount++;
    }

    public int search(Object o) {
        int count = 0;
        Node<E> current = new Node<E>(head.getData());
        while (current.getData() != o) {
            current.getNext();
            count++;
        }
        return count;
    }
}

public class Node<E> 
{
    public E data;
    public Node<E> next;
    // getters and setters  
    public Node(E data) 
    { 
        this.data = data; 
        this.next = null; 
    } 
    public E getData() {
        return this.data;
    }
    public void setData(E data) {
        this.data = data;
    }
    public Node<E> getNext() {
        return next;
    }
    public void setNext(Node<E> next) {
        this.next = next;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

One problem is in your `push` method. There, you are not assigning the new *head* to the member variable defined at class-level. An updated `push` method could look like this:

```
public void push(E data) {
    Node<E> newHead = new Node<>(data);
    newHead.setNext(head);
    head = newHead;
    nodeCount++;
}
```

---

In `peek` you should check if the stack is empty before trying to access `getData()`:

```
public E peek() {
    if (empty()) {
        throw new EmptyStackException();
    }
    return head.getData();
}
```

---

Another `NullPointerException` happens in the `search` method where `head.getData()` is `null` for an empty stack. Furthermore, this method does not report the correct position of an item on the stack. I won't go into details in this answer as you have already asked a [separate question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64299118/make-an-int-searchobject-o-method-for-a-stack-that-uses-nodes).

---

I highly encourage to look into how to use a debugger to step through your code. Thereby, you can execute your program line by line and see where it is deviating from what you expect. Debugging is an essential skill as a programmer. Here are three resources:

- [IntelliJ IDEA Tutorial: Debug your first Java application](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/debugging-your-first-java-application.html)
- [Eclipse Beginner’s Guide to Quick Start Debugging](https://www.eclipse.org/community/eclipse_newsletter/2017/june/article1.php)
- [Java Debugging with Eclipse - Tutorial](https://www.vogella.com/tutorials/EclipseDebugging/article.html)

Comment: That's not the only problem.

Comment: @StephenC Yes, you are right. I updated the answer accordingly.

Comment: And the way that `search` initializes `current` is wrong.  I think we would do better pointing the OP at resources for learning to debug programs ...

Comment: @StephenC Thanks, I added this suggestion which I find valuable. The OP has already asked a separate question for the `search` method (now linked in my answer). That is why I was not going into more detail here.